# Can't build macOS project after updating to Xcode 10.2/Swift 5

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5

My project built fine before updating Xcode.

Now however, I can no longer build the project. When using Swift 5, building the project just never finishes. It stops on "Building 70 of 100 tasks" and just never finishes. Those numbers aren't always the same, either, but it never finishes building.

If I try to use Xcode to convert my project from Swift 4.2 to Swift 5, it similarly never finishes converting.

If I try changing the toolchain to use the Swift 4.2.1 release toolchain, the code compiles successfully but I get this crash immediately at runtime:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _$SBOWV
  Referenced from: /Users/compc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Swift_Coder-hczsehpbafcwkfgwyameucznmhsp/Build/Products/Debug/Swift Coder.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/SavannaKit.framework/Versions/A/SavannaKit
  Expected in: /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib
 in /Users/compc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Swift_Coder-hczsehpbafcwkfgwyameucznmhsp/Build/Products/Debug/Swift Coder.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/SavannaKit.framework/Versions/A/SavannaKit
```

I've tried cleaning the project and deleting derived data but neither seems to work.

The project continues to build and run perfectly fine if I use Xcode 10.1.

Comment: I would suggest filing a bug report with Apple along with the project.

Comment: When the build is running, but not finishing, are you able to look at the build log in the Report navigator (Cmd+9) ? If so, try right-clicking on the Build target step and expand all transcripts. Does it give any clues as to why it is hanging?

Comment: @MikeTaverne Thank you, I've never looked at that screen while building before! It's very helpful. It shows that all of the source files in the third party libraries (SavannaKit and SourceEditor) are compiling fine, yet there are fix source files from my code that never finish compiling. But I have no clue what's wrong with any of the code in those files. It still builds fine in Xcode 10.1, but hangs like this when building in 10.2 when compiling in Swift 4.2 mode or trying to convert to Swift 5.

Comment: I'm not sure if anything is wrong with the files that are failing to compile. For example, this file is one of the five that hang when compiling. It's just a simple struct, I'm not sure what's wrong with it. Again, there are no issues building the project under Xcode 10.1. https://github.com/joshbirnholz/Swift-Coder/blob/master/Swift%20Coder/CompilerMessage.swift

Comment: I added that file to a new project and it had no issues. My guess is there is something about it within the context of your project that is tripping up the compiler. Like matt said, it's probably a bug for Apple to look into. However, that doesn't help you immediately. You might try removing the offending code until you get to a place where the project will build, then add the code back in with necessary workarounds. (I had a problem like this when migrating to Swift 3 and the code was too complex for the compiler.)

Comment: Unfortunately one of the five files that doesn’t compile is the main view controller of my app... and I’m not being given any information as to why it’s not compiling. So K can’t really just remove the offending code because I don’t know which part isn’t working. I can compile that source file from the command line with Swift 5. I get this same problem when downloading the version of that project from GitHub and trying to build it. I’m curious if you tried to build that project if it would work, or if it’s an Xcode issue with just my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had problems with some of my code involving extending the `ClosedRange` type to `Encodable` and `Decodable` in a custom way. In Swift 5, `ClosedRange` already conforms to `Encodable` and `Decodable` when its `Bound` is `Encodable` and `Decodable`, but the compiler wasn't giving me an error about the redundant conformance, instead just hanging on compilation.

After I modified my code to use the new Swift 5 protocol conformance, it compiled fine. It took a long time to narrow down the problem to this, however. It seems to me to be a bug in the Swift Compiler because the compiler hangs in a Playground or from the command line as well, even on a different Mac.

Comment: I agree it’s a bug and I still think you should file it!

Answer (score 1):

Do your project contains any third libraries? If so, try to figure out which one is outdated. Try to build project without this libraries, i'm perfectly sure some of them are just outdated. You may also want to set up swift language version to old one. Select the target, goto Build Settings > Swift Language Version

Comment: I haven't converted to Swift 5 yet. The language is still set as Swift 4.2.

Answer (score 1):

Please delete Derived Data,

You can go to File > Workspace Settings if you are in a workspace environment or File > Project Settings for a regular project environment. Then click over the little grey arrow under Derived data section and select your project folder to delete it.

if you have Pods Than deintegrate and reinstalling all pod files again.

Hope this works for you!

Comment: I’ve tried this already, unfortunately it made no difference.

Comment: i have same issue and this works for me, do you have pod installed?

Comment: I’m not using CocoaPods.

Answer (score 0):

Disable iCloud.

The problem was caused by discrepancies between desktop and icloud!

Spent 24h trying to find why workspace would freeze at launch.

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you added a short tutorial on how to do this you answer would gain some more quality.